# How can I plot several 2D image in a stack style in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In Matlab, I want to plot several 2D image (all data in a 2 dimension matrix in I(x,y) format). I know for a single plot, imagesc(I) could achieve the desired image. However, now, I got a few images and want to put them in a stack format, just like the image shown in [Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1NUj.jpg)

Comment: What you want is called slices, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625091/plotting-a-3d-matrix-in-slices-matlab

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you got hinted, the most useful function for your problem is : [`slice`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html). You should also have a good read at this Mathworks article: [`Exploring Volumes with Slice Planes`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/exploring-volumes-with-slice-planes.html) as it gives more examples on how to work with slice.

In your case, you have the data for each of your slices (each image is a slice), you just need to pack them together so Matlab will interpret them as volumetric data.

Since you didn't give any sample data to work with, I have to generate a small sample. I will use the Matlab function `flow` to generate volumetric data and extract 4 images (4 slices) out of it:

```
%% Generate sample images
[x,y,z,v] = flow; %// x,y,z and v are all of size [25x50x25]

im1 = v(:,:,5);  %// extract the slice at Z=5.  im1 size is [25x50]
im2 = v(:,:,10); %// extract the slice at Z=10. im2 size is [25x50]
im3 = v(:,:,15); %// extract the slice at Z=15. im3 size is [25x50]
im4 = v(:,:,20); %// extract the slice at Z=20. im4 size is [25x50]

hf = figure ;
subplot(221);imagesc(im1);title('Z=5');
subplot(222);imagesc(im2);title('Z=10');
subplot(223);imagesc(im3);title('Z=15');
subplot(224);imagesc(im4);title('Z=20');

%// This is just how I generated sample images, it is not part of the "answer" !
```

Which gives you 4 simple images:
[image]

---

Now is the real fun. Stack all your images in one matrix as if they were just slices:

```
M(:,:,1) = im1 ;
M(:,:,2) = im2 ;
M(:,:,3) = im3 ;
M(:,:,4) = im4 ;
```

You now have a matrix `M [25x50x4]`. *If you have too many images you can work out a loop to stack them*.

From there on, it's just a simple matter of calling `slice` to get your desired picture. Look at the documentation to explore all the possible rendering options. A simple example is:

```
hf2 = figure ;
hs = slice(M,[],[],1:4) ;
shading interp
set(hs,'FaceAlpha',0.8);
```

Which produces:
[image]

---

note: This uses the default indexing, which should be good for the problem you describe (simply stacking some images). If you want your volume to have real coordinates, you can build a coordinate system with [`ndgrid`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html). Ex:

```
[xs,ys,zs] = ndgrid( 1:25 , 1:50 , 1:4 ) ;
```

will create a grid/coordinate system of size `[25x50x4]`. Just replace the numbers to build the grid coordinate you need.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange them all in a 3D Matrix. This would be arranging them such that you get  `stack(i,j,k)`, where `stack(i,:,:)` gives you a particular image and `i` is the the slice number. Once this is done, use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21993-viewer3d) library. `Viewer3D` pretty much lets you visualize everything in an interactive 3D GUI and also performs interpolation. However, there should be a positive correlation in the data between the slices, or the 3D image is not going to appear to make sense.