# how to fix these errors in my matlab code?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to stack 2D images to get 3D just like
[How can I plot several 2D image in a stack style in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549733/how-can-i-plot-several-2d-image-in-a-stack-style-in-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1)

my original code had some errors and someone suggested to go with the below code

```
M = zeros(25, 50, 8);
for k = 1:8
    img = imread(sprintf('%d-0000.jpg', k + 30));
    img = imresize(img, [25 50]);
    img = im2double(rgb2gray(img));  % Convert to double format
    M(:, :, k) = img;
end
hf2 = figure ;
hs = slice(M,[],[],1:8) ;
shading interp
set(hs,'FaceAlpha',0.8);
```

this is the expected result
[How can I plot several 2D image in a stack style in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549733/how-can-i-plot-several-2d-image-in-a-stack-style-in-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1)

this is the error I get

> Error using rgb2gray>parse_inputs (line 81)
>     MAP must be a m x 3 array.
>
> Error in rgb2gray (line 35)
>   X = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
>
> Error in stack2 (line 9)
>         img = im2double(rgb2gray(img));  % Convert to double format

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix 'subscripted assignment dimension mismatch' in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396517/how-to-fix-subscripted-assignment-dimension-mismatch-in-matlab)

Comment: Please don’t post the same question twice. Instead, edit your first question to properly explain your problem. A well-poses question will get answered eventually.

Comment: i have deleted that post that error was rectified now i get new error as in my screen shot @CrisLuengo

Comment: I said the above because it’s exactly the same screen shot you had on the other question. Please copy-paste the error message, don’t use images of text, they’re not searchable and not everyone can read from an image. Also see [mcve]. I can’t reproduce your problem because I don’t have your data. That means I can only guess at what the problem might be, which is not conductive to writing an answer. This is why you only had comments to your other question.

Comment: To your other question you had gotten some really good suggestions from gnovice: “The images you load from file have to be 3-D RGB images for your code to work. Based on the screenshot you added, your third image 33-0000.jpg is likely an indexed color image, meaning you have to use ind2gray to convert it.” and “Because you have to load the image and map, and pass both to ind2gray.“ (which came with proper formatting and links to relevant examples, I’m too lazy to copy these, go look at those links!!!)

Comment: In particular, the documentation to `ind2gray` comes with an example that exactly explains how to load the color map from the file and apply it to the image.

Comment: ok i will paste the error message.

Comment: i do not know how to use ind2grey . seems it need 2 arguments.

Comment: The expected result is that StackOverflow question?  I don't get it

Comment: It is literally the first example in the documentation for `ind2gray`. It shows you how to get two values out of `imread` and put them into `ind2gray`. https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ind2gray.html#d117e180249

Comment: @C.Peck i tried to recreate the exact same result for another set of images but it wouldn't run for the new images i set. the program ran fine for his example also it was years since that question asked and the person who answered that question seems to be inactive now

Comment: thankyou @CrisLuengo. i read that page since the new program was suggested by another user i do not know how to implement ind2grey any changes i make gives me expression error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as it's written is designed to work with [3-D RGB images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468). However, the screenshot of your workspace suggests not all of your images fit that criteria. When `k` is 3, `img` is a 2-D matrix, meaning that the image in file "33-0000.jpg" is either already a [grayscale image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-175) or an [indexed image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-155) for which you didn't load the associated map.

To solve this, you will need to add some additional logic to your loop when loading your image so that you can identify what image type it is and how to properly convert it. Specifically, you need to check the [number of dimensions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndims.html) of the image data and whether or not [`imread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) returns an associated colormap. Then you can apply [`rgb2gray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) or [`ind2gray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ind2gray.html) as needed. For example:

```
for k = 1:8
  [img, cmap] = imread(sprintf('%d-0000.jpg', k + 30));
  if ~isempty(cmap)         % There is a colormap, so it's indexed
    img = ind2gray(img, cmap);
  elseif (ndims(img) == 3)  % 3 dimensions, so it's RGB
    img = rgb2gray(img);
  end
  M(:, :, k) = imresize(im2double(img), [25 50]);  % Convert to double and resize
end
```