# I need a function to display matrices stacked

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, slice, matlab-figure

So I have a bunch of matrices like so:

[image]

That I'd like to display stacked like so:
[image]

The thing is that this example was taken from the slice function which I though to use but then realized it just shows slices from 3d data. However, my data is a bunch of 2d matrices with a certain spacial separation and no data between them. I guess I could put them in a 3d array where all the other layers are 0 and only slice in the layers where I know I have data, but I feel like there has got to be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Yes, put them together, without padding with zeroes inbetween. in `slice` you can chose which slices to slice. You can chose to slice them all.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The thing is, not all my planes are equally spaced, and I'd like to display them to scale, i.e. have them displayed with different distances

Comment: This question is very similar to this one: [How can I plot several 2D image in a stack style in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35549733/3460361). May be my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35552548/3460361) to it works for you too.

Comment: As Luis suggests, you can tell `slice` in which `x,y,z` values does your matrix lie. You can define everything.

Comment: @Hoki I think we should mark this question as duplicate of the one you linked, do you agree?

Comment: @LuisMendo, I was hesitating because there is already a good valid answer here, but I agree the two questions and their solutions are really similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the slice positions to coincide with the data, so no interpolation takes place.

Example:

```
A = cat(3, fspecial('gaussian',9,2), ...
           .03*eye(9), ...
           fspecial('gaussian',9,2.4), ...
           zeros(9,9), ...
           fspecial('gaussian',9,2.8)); % example data
slice(1:size(A,1), 1:size(A,2), 1:size(A,3), A, [], [], 1:size(A,3))
```

[image]