# How to stack a series of images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, imaging

```
clc;clear all;


Imatrix = []
for i=1:3

  images{i} = imread(sprintf('frame-1065.png',i));
  Imatrix = cat(3, Imatrix, images{i});
  D = Imatrix;

end;

imshow(D)
```

This is the code I'm trying to run but the problem is I have 2000 pictures and I am only able to get one to be displayed.

Comment: `sprintf('frame-1065.png',i)` always gives the same result irrespective of the value of `i`. What do you mean by stacking images?

Comment: I have a set of images that go from 1 to 2456 and I need to create a 3D plot by stacking on top of eachoter. Therefore I started by creating that loop, but it seems not to work

Comment: You mean that you're looking for a composite image?

Comment: I am trying to get a volume out of a set of images by stacking them all together

Comment: `imshow` doesn't show volume images, but there are other tools in MATLAB that you can use for that. Also, if you're going to work with volumetric images, I'd recommend that you use the [DIPimage](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/releases) toolbox for MATLAB. With DIPimage you can do: `readtimeseries('frame-*.png')` to read in all images, stack them into a 3D image, and display it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I plot several 2D image in a stack style in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549733/how-can-i-plot-several-2d-image-in-a-stack-style-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really want is to store the images as image stacks.
This will allow you to view the image stack in e.g. [ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Welcome) and scroll through it etc.

I would store them as one single tiff file and do something like this (please note that all your images must be of the same size):

```matlab
numOfImages = 2000;
output_filename = 'imgstack.tif';
for k=1:numOfImages
    loaded_image = imread(sprintf('frame-%d.png',k));
    imwrite(loaded_image, output_filename, 'WriteMode',append','Compression','none');
end
```

Comment: your suggestion was great! only issue your code does not let me loop through pictures from 1 to 1256...how should I do it?

Comment: @VegaOmega Yes, it does. It loops through from `1` to `numOfImages`.  Set the variable `numOfImages = 1256` and you should be on your way. You may need to adjust the the filename though but I took it from your question.

Comment: Dear @kkuilla I tried that method, but as you can see I get this error.

Comment: @VegaOmega Fixed that.. Apologies...

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you very much, that was very kind from your part.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is visualization. You can view either an MxNxP stack or a cell array where each cell represents an image using the montage function.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html

```
figure, montage(images)
```

In your code above.

If you want to visualize your data as a volume, which you've indicated in the most recent comment, then volshow or volumeViewer in IPT will do that.

```
volumeViewer(Imatrix)
figure, volshow(Imatrix)
```

Where Imatrix is an MxNxP array that you want to perform volume visualization on.

Comment: There is a problem, I want to create a VOLUME with these images, not a multiframe image array.

Comment: See my updates. In the future, I'd recommend including information like that in your OP for best results on StackOverflow.